# Difference between null: false and required: true in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

In rails migrations what is the difference between `null: false` and `required: true`?

For eg. if I write:

```
t.string      :phone_number,      required: true
```

is it same as:

```
t.string      :phone_number,      null: false
```

If both are different then how exactly do they differ?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Use `null: false` I have never seen anyone ever use `required: true` In fact I don't see it in the rails guides.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Comment: Where did you see this example? `required: true` doesn't do anything in a migration, doesn't throw an error though.

Comment: Using `required: true` won't throw an error. It will be a hash parameter to `t.string` which is simply ignored.

Comment: @Iceman I saw this being used in a code excerpt and I posted it on stack as I could not find any explanation for it online. Well, now I know why I didn't find any explanation online. Thanks all :)

Answer (score 5):

`required:true` doesn't do anything in migrations. Are you perhaps getting confused with [Active Record Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)?

TL;DR: Use `null:false`.